# How to redirect between 2 dashboards in Kibana4?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

This might sound a bit confusing but here it goes.

I have a 'Default' dashboard which shows a combination of visualization and dashboards. Basically i am showing a lot of customers on a default dashboard.
The entries on this dashboard will remain same and the search will narrow down once the  user clicks a particular customer on visualization {say bar-chart}.

Now I want that when user clicks on the bar chart or does a search like *cust_name* , it should show a another dashboard instead of the default one which i configured for "customer specific detail"

I am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in Kibana 4.x.

You can define the dashboards you desire to be opened and add the filtering visualization from the main one.
Also you can write a simple web page to call embedded kibana dashboards with queries injected when calling the dashboards.